# Blank value handle for Map field in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I have following code :-

```
val curRow: com.datastax.driver.core.Row
val stats = curRow.getMap[String, Int]("stats", classOf[String], classOf[Int])
stats = Map("d1" -> 1, "d2" -> 0)
stats.get("d1").getOrElse(0)
stats.get("d2").getOrElse(0)
stats.get("d3").getOrElse(0)
```

I have created a case class with a map column. Now wanted to handle it for no field. For "d3" If I write only .get - I get error as None.get and If I try to handle it with getOrElse, I cannot do this.

```
type mismatch; found : Any required: Int
```

What should I do to handle for blank field in case of Integer.

Thanks,

Comment: By blank field do you mean that the key-value pair is not present in the map.

Comment: yes @ChaitanyaWaikar

Comment: Can you add the relevant code for the case class and where you're getting the error?

Comment: @philantrovert - yes actually the code is quiet big . So I have just shared saturated part but will try to give more details of code , check my question again in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

The stats map should be a Map[String,Int] and not Map[String,Integer] as this will correspond to java.lang.Integer.

```
val stats: Map[String, Int] = Map("d1" -> 1, "d2" -> 9)
stats.get("d1").getOrElse(0)
stats.get("d2").getOrElse(0)
stats.get("d3").getOrElse(0)
```

gives an output as

```
stats: Map[String,Int] = Map(d1 -> 1, d2 -> 9)
res0: Int = 1
res1: Int = 9
res2: Int = 0
```

Hence, once you make this change, you will not get the error.

Comment: @Pinnacle please let me know if this answers your question. Thanks

Comment: It gives me another error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primitive type 'int' used as type parameter

Comment: Its Int and not int

Comment: Yes , I have written Int and not int .. So, I tried to debug and found one point. If you check my ques again. My data is coming in rows to this point so here i have to extract it in val. So error is generated at this point - curRow.getMap[String, Int]("stats", classOf[String], classOf[Int])